# Angular Directive Element dynamic Template fields with its updated model value from controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have `<superhero>` directive which has two directive

- **web-buttons** to take of the form validation and post the updated
  ngModel value to respective controller
- **fieldMap** directive to generate the dynamic fields by object we are passing from respective controller

Here is the [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/PI8s1UXGKttCpJrtWMrA?p=preview) which i have worked

directive attribute called **saveFormFn** will tell the button to call which function to invoked using **enter** attribute directive.

For example. After click save button it will call the function '**Ctrl1saveFormFn**' from controller **Ctrl1** .This function will make ajax post to save the form fields.

After updating the text fields with some content and click save,I have passed the current scope of the  directive to respective controller (see console log). i could not get the updated **fielddata** value from current Scope.

```
$scope.Ctrl1saveFormFn = function(item){
        _.each(item,function(currentScope){
            console.log(currentScope)
            // here i want to collect the form data with updated fielddata values
        })
    }
```

I am beginner.Am i on right path? Please advice

Answer (score 0):

I've re-written your code because it was pretty hard to understand.

I would do it like this:

1. Use `ng-include` to load the template of your buttons. That's loading the control buttons `edit` and `save`.
2. Save your data in a variable in the `superhero` directive. Maybe it would be even better to store it in a separate service/factory.
3. Create a directive `customForm` that will create a form based on the supplied model that you're passing to its scope.
4. The main application logic is in the `superhero` directive because it is adding the controls save/edit to the DOM. If saving/editing is not only related to the `superhero` it would be better to do it in your main controller.

Please have a look at the demo below or in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/yj6fa9ze/).

```js
angular.module('demoApp', [])
    .directive('superhero', Superhero)
    .directive('customForm', CustomForm)
    .controller('mainController', MainController);

function Superhero() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            formModel: "=",
        },
        template: '<div class="hero"><div ng-include="\'web-buttons.html\'"></div><custom-form model="formModel"></custom-form></div>',
        controllerAs: 'superHeroCtrl',
        controller: function ($scope) {
            var self = this;
            console.log('controller directive');
            angular.extend(this, {
                abilities: [],
                editMode: false,
                
                addStrength: function (data) {
                    self.abilities.push(data);
                },
                getStrength: function () {
                    return self.abilities;
                },
                showSave: function() {
                    self.editMode = true;
                    $scope.formModel.editMode = true;
                },
                hideSave: function() {
                    self.editMode = false;
                    $scope.formModel.editMode = false;
                },
                save: function() {
                    self.addStrength('can fly');
                    console.log(self.getStrength());
                    console.log('saving data now of form now...', $scope.formModel.data);
                    alert('saving data of form now: ' + self.getStrength()[0] + ' - ' + JSON.stringify( $scope.formModel.data, null, 2));
                    self.hideSave();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}

function CustomForm() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            model: '='
        },
        template: '<div ng-if="model.editMode" ng-repeat="formElement in model.fields" ng-include="formElement.template.url"></div>'
    }
}

function MainController() {
    this.normalForm = {
        editMode: false,
        data: {
        },
        fields: {
            'NAME':{
                template: {
                    url: 'customForms/text.html',
                    type: 'edit' // not sure for what it is needed
                },
                label: 'First name',
                id: "NAME",
                placeholder : "First Name",
                fieldData: "NAME",
                key : 'first_name'
            },
            'LNAME': {
                template: {
                    url: 'customForms/text.html',
                    type: 'edit' // not sure for what it is needed
                },
                label: "Last Name",
                placeholder : "Last Name",
                id: "LNAME",
                key : 'last_name'
            }
        }
    };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="mainController as mainCtrl">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="customForms/text.html">
        <label for="{{formElement.id}}">{{formElement.label}}</label>
        <input ng-model="model.data[formElement.key]" placeholder="{{formElement.placeholder}}" id="formElement.id"/>
    </script>
    
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="web-buttons.html">
        <button ng-click="superHeroCtrl.showSave()" ng-if="!superHeroCtrl.editMode">edit</button>
        <button ng-if="superHeroCtrl.editMode" ng-click="superHeroCtrl.save()">save</button>
    </script>
    
    <superhero form-model="mainCtrl.normalForm"></superhero>
    <h3>debug output:</h3>
    <pre>
    {{mainCtrl.normalForm |json}}
    </pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Take me take look into this